# How does this USB capacitive touch light circuit work? You can touch anywhere and it turns on, not just the electrode

Tags: led, usb, touchscreen, pcb-layers

Here are some pics of the circuit board.

[image]

Now I'm not asking how the circuit works, I understand that. There is a [capacitive touch sensor IC](http://www.tontek.com.tw/download.asp?sn=475) where the shiny electrode you see on top connects to the input. Then the output drives a transistor which turns on the LED when you touch. The capacitor on the left is a sensitivity adjustment connected between the electrode input and GND.

**However, if I touch the side of the PCB, or even the back, the circuit works 100% of the time.** At first I thought maybe the back was electrically connected to the electrode input with vias, but I scraped away all of the solder mask (and more) but found nothing. It wasn't even conductive.

So does anyone know why this circuit works even when you touch areas that aren't electrically connected to the input, or even connected anywhere for that matter? Is there a certain PCB stackup you use, or some other trick that isn't obvious to me?

Answer (score 1):

Cap sense doesn't actually require touch, just a change in the baseline capacitance. This can be touch less if sensitive enough. While that board has a large copper plane for touch,  The entire board is thin enough for the cap sense to work.

Comment: So would it help even more if the input electrode was connected to the back layer with vias and just a large exposed copper pad?

Comment: Any help on this?